# How to I highlight search results in a webview like Safari and NSTextView showFindIndicatorForRange:

Tags: cocoa, webkit

In Safari, and in an NSTextView on OSX, search results can be highlighted with a bright yellow box that has a little animated pop.  Is there any way to do this in a webview without coding it all myself?

Comment: Hi Mike. Did you succeed at this?

Answer (score 3):

I did find a way to do this.

See [showFindIndicatorForRange:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextView/showFindIndicatorForRange%3a).

Comment: showFindIndicatorForRange: is a method of NSTextView.  I need this functionality in a WebView.  I'm highlighting the text using methods in WebView but I don't have the animation.  There is probably a javascript solution but I haven't looked into it.

Comment: Maybe not the answer to the original question, but exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

The answer (as of 2013-05) seems to be that you have to highlight the find results in the webview manually (ref: ["Implementing a Find menu item like Safari?" thread from 2011](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2011/Jan/msg00813.html)), although it's a [long-planned webkit feature](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Webkitsdk-dev/2008/Feb/msg00032.html).

I'll list the links I found while researching this.

- There's [HighlightedWebView](https://github.com/Kapeli/HighlightedWebView) but at the time of writing it appears to insert `<span>`s to highlight the search terms.
- I couldn't find an answer on how to mimic this effect with Core Animation:

  - [Core animation - Safari Find effect](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/229471-core-animation-safari-find-effect.html) on cocoa-dev has an overview of the solution, but no code
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187511/mimicking-showfindindicatorforrange-with-calayer here on SO has no answers
- On WebView and NSTextFinder (the standard find bar interface):

  - [How do I get NSTextFinder to show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489765/how-do-i-get-nstextfinder-to-show-up) here on SO is related, but it doesn't seem it's about this exact problem.
  - [NSTextFinder reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTextFinder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (the *"Text View Support for the Find Bar"* section) suggests it can draw "the yellow find indicator background bezel" for any NSView/NSScrollView if it supports NSTextFinderClient (which WebView does not - ref.: [[1]](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3640#c15), [[2]](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/327153-webview-find-panel-bar-implementation.html)).
  - ["WebView find panel/bar implementation"](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/327153-webview-find-panel-bar-implementation.html) on [cocoa-dev](http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2013/Apr/msg00007.html) is the most recent (2013-04) thread on this and it contains an overview of the possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this open source WebView subclass (MIT License) that incorporates NSTextFinder support:

https://github.com/shc-vj/SHCWebView

as well as the WebKit source itself for its MiniBrowser test app:

https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Tools/MiniBrowser/mac/WK2BrowserWindowController.m

The MiniBrowser's window controller implements NSTextFinderBarContainer so it doesn't have to put its WebView inside an otherwise superfluous scrollview for the find bar to work.