# What is Cocoa control for implementing Google Chrome Search?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, google-chrome

What is Cocoa control for implementing Search Panel of Google Chrome or Safari ? I mean I'd like to implement a panel that appears below toolbar and containing a textfield plus next and prev button. I don't mind if it is similar to Chrome or Safari.

[image]

Comment: chrome has it's own. maybe you mean the control which is in safari? please update your question.

Comment: updated. I'd like to have a panel that appears/disappears when user searches

Comment: Are you looking for high level guidance (direction)?  Or, are you looking for someone to implement for you?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: direction. I found this and I am going to try: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/298178-implementing-find-menu-item-like-safari.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in control with that appearance or behaviour. You will have to roll your own.

Comment: I updated. I'd like to implement a panel that appears when I want to search

Comment: There *was* no built-in control with that appearance or behavior—before Lion.

Comment: @Peter: Which control are you thinking of? Closest I can think of is a combo box and that's not really that close.

Comment: Ah, you mean `NSTextFinder`? From the original question, it's not evident that's what @piero is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you can require Lion, you can use [NSTextFinder](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTextFinder_Class/Reference/Reference.html). That's the standard Find bar used in TextEdit; you can use it with any view, providing you give it an object that implements [the `NSTextFinderClient` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTextFinderClient_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSTextFinderClient).

If your view is a custom view, that probably should be the client object. If your view is a WebView, I'm not sure whether you'll be able to use the view as the client or not. It depends on whether WebView implements the protocol. If not, you'll need to make your own client object.

Comment: No, WebView doesn't implement NSTextFinderClient, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16511485/1026